# offset in grid system doesn't take effect?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

this is my code:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">

  <div style={{border: 'solid black 0.5px'}} class="col-md-3">
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus,</p>
    <p><a className="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>

  <div style={{border: 'solid black 0.5px'}} class="col-md-3 offset-md-4">
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, </p>
    <p><a className="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>

  <div style={{border: 'solid black 0.5px'}} class="col-md-3 offset-md-1">
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, </p>
    <p><a className="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

I have used offset on heading 2, the one in the center but it doesn't skip some space unlike in the docs? what I wanted to do is add some margin on them but when I try to, it pushes the last one on the bottom or it doesn't occupy all the  space, if I don't use 4? how do I add margin here?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's `col-md-offset-4` and not `offset-md-4`
read better the docs again https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-offsetting